# how to set scope and element when using audio unit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

I am developing a karaoke software.and intend to mix the audio by using audiounit,but I don't know how to set the scope and element?for example:

```
UInt32 busCount = 2;
OSStatus result = AudioUnitSetProperty (
    mixerUnit,
    kAudioUnitProperty_ElementCount
    kAudioUnitScope_Input,
    0,
    &busCount,
    sizeof (busCount
);
```

why the scope is 'kAudioUnitScope_Input' and element is '0',what's the meaning of this?

Answer (score 6):

This illustration from [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals.html) make it pretty clear:

[image]

> A scope is a programmatic context within an audio unit. Although the name global scope might suggest otherwise, these contexts are
>   never nested. You specify the scope you are targeting by using a
>   constant from the Audio Unit Scopes enumeration.

The 0 refers to "output bus".

> An element is a programmatic context nested within an audio unit scope. When an element is part of an input or output scope, it is
>   analogous to a signal bus in a physical audio device—and for that
>   reason is sometimes called a bus. These two terms—element and
>   bus—refer to exactly the same thing in audio unit programming. This
>   document uses “bus” when emphasizing signal flow and uses “element”
>   when emphasizing a specific functional aspect of an audio unit, such
>   the input and output elements of an I/O unit (see “Essential
>   Characteristics of I/O Units”).

It's best to use defines to give the bus values semantics:

```
// put this in header file
#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for bringing in the diagram!

Answer (score 1):

The `AudioUnitSetProperty` is defined as

```
OSStatus AudioUnitSetProperty (
   AudioUnit            inUnit,
   AudioUnitPropertyID  inID,
   AudioUnitScope       inScope,
   AudioUnitElement     inElement,
   const void           *inData,
   UInt32               inDataSize
);
```

where the 0, in your code, correspond to the `AudioUnitElement` and the `kAudioUnitScope_Input`  is your defined `AudioUnitScope`, which is explained as

> Scope - the programmatic context, within an audio unit, that the property applies to.
>   A property applies to one or more scopes, as described in this document. The audio unit scopes
>   in iOS are Input, Output, and Global. In OS X, audio units have additional, MIDI-related scopes:
>   Group, Part, and Note.

Take a look at the documentation of [AudioUnitSetProperty](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioUnitSetProperty) 
as well as [Audio Unit Properties Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitPropertiesReference/Reference/reference.html)